# How to open images saved in user created folder in internal memory in android

Tags: android

I am creating an android app in which i am editing images and saving these images in the folder created by me.
Now want to show only all my edited  images in my app in grid view on a button click.I am able to show the all images saved in gallery  by this link https://dzone.com/articles/displaying-images-sd-card but i want to show only images from my folder only.

Code to save images is.......

```
RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
            content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();

            File myDir=new File("/sdcard/MyCollection");
            myDir.mkdirs();
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
            File file = new File (myDir, fname);
            if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
            boolean success = false;
            FileOutputStream outStream;
            try {

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);

                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
                success = true;

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I want to show all images saved in my folder "MyCollection" created in device storage . Please help me i m very confused..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
    File f = new File(cacheDir, String.valueOf("fileName"));
     try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        //o.inPreferredConfig =  Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; // Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int REQUIRED_SIZE1=120;
        if(isLargeImage){
            REQUIRED_SIZE1=250;
        }
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = REQUIRED_SIZE1;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
```

Comment: It is Just Path of the folder where image is stored

Comment: you will have to add complete path like android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myimage/"

Comment: Actully my folder is in file manager in device storage and i want to show all stored images in it.

Comment: Please look this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

it fetch images from URL and save in local sd card and then show in ImageView

Comment: Sory sir  i m new in android  so please give me some easy solution if it is possible